# Google AdSense: Changing a background color to transparent

Tags: javascript, css, adsense

I'm sure it's possible.  I know some websites already do the same thing:

Example : [Search on Conduit](http://search.conduit.com)

Type something for search, for example "Hosting" or "Rayban", and look at the first three results.  They are AdSense blocks, but with a transparent background !?

How can this be ?

I added a Google Custom Search Element to my website. I already modified the look and feel of the CSE, but I can't modify the look of the ads element since it is inside of an iframe.

Does anybody know how to set-up the style of the ads iframe? I want to put in a background color and change the font.

Comment: However, it might be in violation of the Google Adsense TOS. And I'm not even sure, if the other person is using Adsense.

Comment: And a possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8841818/google-adsense-transparent-background

Comment: can you post your site url? I've some ideas but I need to see your code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Adsense transparent background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8841818/google-adsense-transparent-background)

Answer (score 0):

The last zero in `background-color` makes the opacity of the color transparent:

```
ins {
    color: #000 !important;
    background-color: rgba(119, 25, 0, 0) !important;
}
```